# Positive definite definition

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

I'm looking at the notes on [http://www.math.sci.hokudai.ac.jp/~s.settepanella/teachingfile/Calculus/Calculus1/pagine/lecture8.pdf](http://www.math.sci.hokudai.ac.jp/%7Es.settepanella/teachingfile/Calculus/Calculus1/pagine/lecture8.pdf).

It says the following are equivalent for a symmetric $H$:

(1) $H$ is positive definite.

(2) $x^THx > 0$

(3) $\lambda_i(H) > 0$

(4) $\det(H) > 0$ !??????

(5) Diagonal entries of $H_{ii}$ are positive !?????

(4) and (5) do not seem they belong. (4) is a necessary condition for $H$ to be positive definite, but not a sufficient one. Consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix with 2 negative eigenvalues. The matrix is not positive definite but have a positive determinant.  I've actually never heard of (5) before unless we're talking about diagonal matrix. Isn't this one wrong too?

Answer (score 3):

(4) is false. For a counterexample consider $H = -I$ where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Then for any nonzero $x$, we have $x^T H x = -x^T x < 0$, so $H$ is not positive definite.

(5) is also false. Consider $H = \displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, which has determinant $-3$. This means that one of its eigenvalues is negative; in particular, $\lambda = -1$ is an eigenvalue  with, for example, eigenvector $x = \displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $x^T H x = x^T(Hx) = x^T(\lambda x) = -x^T x < 0$, so $H$ is not positive definite.

Comment: It is surprising that there are such blatant mistakes in course notes that do not appear to be typos.

Comment: @anonuser01 Its definition of indefinite matrices is wrong too. A real symmetric matrix is called indefinite if it is neither positive *semidefinite* nor negative *semidefinite*, not if it is neither positive definite nor negative definite. The zero matrix for instance is not indefinite.